# Phonegap Plugin Push notification stays in tray when clicked on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, notifications, phonegap-plugins

I built a phonegap application which receives push notifications. When I run the application on Android, everything works perfectly, but when I run it on iOS, the push notifications stay in the notification tray after clicking them.

I am using Phonegap Push Plugin for the Phonegap application and I'm using PushSharp for sending the notification. This is my code:

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
    "android": { "senderID": "XXXXXXXX", "icon":"pushicon" },
    "ios": { "alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true"},
    "windows": {}
});
push.on('registration', function(data) {
    var deviceInfo = {
        notificationId: data.registrationId,
        phonePlatform: device.platform,
        phoneVersion: device.version,
        phoneModel: device.model
    }
    info = $.extend(info, deviceInfo);
    localStorageService.setDeviceInfo(info);
});
push.on('notification', function (data) {
    alert(data.additionalData.title);
});
push.on('error', function(e) {
    console.log('Something went wrong: ' + e.message);
});
```

I've also tried calling push.finish(), but it makes no difference.

Does anybody know how I can make sure a notification on the notification tray dissapears after clicking on it?

**Specs**

- Device: iPod Touch with iOS 7.0.4
- Plugin: Phonegap plugin push

Comment: On which iOS version are you testing?

Comment: I'm testing on an iPod Touch with iOS 7.0.4

Comment: Can you please specify, which plugin you have used for push notification?

Comment: I am using phonegap plugin push (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS 8 and greater, when you tap the push it will be deleted from notification center, but on iOS 7 and older it doesn't work that way.

If you want to delete the push notification from notification center you'll have to set the badge to 0.

```
push.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(function() {
    console.log('success');
}, function() {
    console.log('error');
}, 0);
```

If it doesn't work you can try to set it to a greater number first and then to 0

```
push.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(function() {
    push.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(function() {
        console.log('success');
    }, function() {
        console.log('error');
    }, 0);
}, function() {
    console.log('error');
}, 2);
```

Latest version of the plugin also has a `clearAllNotifications` method:

```
push.clearAllNotifications(function() {
    console.log('success');
}, function() {
    console.log('error');
});
```

Or you can also pass the clearBadge option to the init method

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
    "android": { "senderID": "XXXXXXXX", "icon":"pushicon" },
    "ios": { "alert": "true", "badge": "true", "sound": "true", clearBadge: "true" },
    "windows": {}
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The notification stays in the tray. Isn't the icon badge number the number on the app's icon instead of the notification in the notification tray?

Comment: It's the number of the icon, but should delete all the notifications on the tray too.

Comment: try calling it twice, first with 1 and then with 0

Comment: Nope, nothing happens. When I call it with just 1, the icon does get a 1 in the corner, so the function does work, but calling 1 and then 0 has no effect.

Comment: In which iOS version are you testing?

Comment: I am using an iPod Touch with iOS 7.0.4

Comment: Ok, will take a look.

Comment: Sorry, it took me a while but I've updated the answer and I've tested it and all of the ways of doing it are working.